# Notes.app on Mountain Lion: How can I change the default folder view?

Tags: macos, icloud, notes.app

I use the Notes app with iCloud. The 'Notes' folder under 'iCloud' is set as my default account under Notes > Default Account > iCloud. This ensures that new notes are created in iCloud instead of on my Mac. However, I also have notes folders in the 'On My Mac' section. I actually only use this so that I have a local backup of my iCloud notes.

[image: Notes app Folders List]

The problem is that the default view when I open the app is 'All Notes'. This means that my notes are duplicated: I see both the notes in iCloud and the local backup copies. The app doesn't 'remember' the view selected when the app was last closed.

Is there any way of forcing Notes.app to show only iCloud notes by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the answer's 'no', then. Will send feedback to Apple about it and hope that it changes in a future update.